# How to cut a plane

Tags: cloth-simulation, knife-tool

Is there a way to cut a slice through a plane, like through a piece of paper?
Specifically, I created a plane, gave it a thickness, and applied a cloth modifier to it. The cloth is supposed to be hair on a head (Its not supposed to look realistic) and I want there to be several, large hair strands, all connected at the top. Do I have to create them all individually, or can I cut the single cloth so it has several long tassels? Can you only cut if it cuts through the whole thing?
I tried the knife tool but it didn't seem to work. I might have done it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got what you ask, you could achieve this in this way.

1. Start using a cylinder, not a plane
2. delete the bottom face, and some "front" sides (see image below)
3. then go in edit mode
4. select a side edge, and
5. use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> and "edge ring" to select a "ring" of all side edges, which become selected
6. then use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> and "edge split" to suplicate every selected edge: this will make all dide "quad" faces belonging to all selected edges, independent from the others
7. then, you can "move" any side "quad" as you wished, but they will be still connected to the top round face.
8. then if you wish you can give depth and clothify your "cloth hair" setup

[image]

Comment: Aha, yes, that works!
Or at least the Edge Split does. I decided to use a different shape, and I have to split each edge, but at least it works!